# How to Update Navigate State without Leaving Current Location?

Tags: reactjs

When a user navigates from `projects` page to the page of a single `project`, the project information is passed via a state as:

```
<Link
    to={`/project/${project.id}`}
    state={{
        project: project,
    }}>
    Click Me
</Link>
```

On the project page, I retrieve the project variable using:

```
const [project, setProject] = useState()
const state = useLocation().state

useEffect(() => { 
    if(!!state && 'project' in state) { // parameters passed
        setProject(state.project)
    }
}, [])
```

If user interacts with the page and project variable needs to be changed, I can handle that via `setProject()`, however, if the user the refreshes the page, the old `project` from `useLocation().state` is loaded.

Hence, whenever I update `project`, I need to ensure that it's updated in `useLocation().state` as well. How can I do that?

Comment: you can use local storage to save state,first look into localstorage for initial state,if not found try to get it from location,if you get it from location save it to localstorage ,and at unmount remove it from local storage,this has to be done inside you product detials component

Comment: Yes, including local storage would work I imagine. I managed to figure it out via simply navigating to the same location I am already in, just with updating the state.

Comment: good,but question is How to Update Navigate State without Leaving Current Location?,by using navigate you are leaving current location,no matter its the same page

Answer (score 0):

I have simply resolved to navigating to the same location I am in and carrying the new state whenever `project` updates:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!!project) {
        navigate(`/project/${project.id}`, { 
            state: {
                ...state,
                project: project
            }
         })
    }
}, [project])
```